# Access salesforce API version of a class in Apex

Tags: apex, api

I have a few classes that need to be kept at the same Salesforce API version since they interact with Salesforce metadata that may change between API versions. Because of this I would like to be able to create a unit test that ensures that these classes are using the same API version. This would prevent us from packaging when the class API versions are not the same.

Is there a way to dynamically get the Salesforce API version of a class using Apex?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can perform a SoQL query on the `ApexClass` object:

```
ApexClass apexClass = [
  SELECT ApiVersion
  FROM ApexClass
  WHERE Name = 'MyClassName'
];

System.debug(apexClass.ApiVersion);
//27.0
```

Don't worry, the records will be visible without needing `SeeAllData=true`

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the API version from the developer console.

SELECT Id, NamespacePrefix, Name, ApiVersion, Status FROM ApexClass where NamespacePrefix = ''